# Camera and colour identification

Tags: android, colors, android-camera

I'm trying to write an app that tells the user any colour placed in the camera preview. A small section of the preview is marked and when that section is pointed at a color. The app tells the user what color that is in real time. I have the camera preview class written but now I just need to know how to go about analysing what the camera sees. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply get bitmap image at that time and use bitmap.getpixel(int x,int y) to get color.